# winSCP error System.FormatException Invalid format string

Tags: c#, ssh, scp, winscp

Wanting to copy files from windows to a remote linux computer in C#, using winSCP to do it, pretty much copied the [example C# code](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library#example), but I get an error.

```
        try
        {
            // Setup session options

            SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
            {
                Protocol = Protocol.Scp,
                HostName = "192.168.0.2",
                UserName = "opie",
                Password = "opie",
                //SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
            };

            using (Session session = new Session())
            {
                // Connect
                session.DisableVersionCheck = true;
                sessionOptions.GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = true;
                session.Open(sessionOptions);

                // Upload files
                TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
                transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

                TransferOperationResult transferResult;
                transferResult = session.PutFiles(@"H:\toupload\*", "/home/opie/test.txt", false, transferOptions);

                // Throw on any error
                transferResult.Check();

                // Print results
                foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
                {
                    //Debug.Log("Upload of {0} succeeded", transfer.FileName);
                    Debug.Log("Upload of " + transfer.FileName + " succeeded");
                }
            }
            Debug.Log("winSCP connection succeeded");
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Error: {0}" + e);
            Debug.Log("Error:" + e);
            return;
        }
```

I haven't tried too much to fix it, as I'm at a loss. I'm not sure what other ways to format the file paths (I assume that's the problem), and I'm formatting them the same as in the examples given!

**error given is:**

`FormatException: Invalid format string
System.DateTime.ParseExact (System.String s, System.String[] formats, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/DateTime.cs:1892)
System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime (System.String s, System.String[] formats, DateTimeStyles style)
System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime (System.String s, System.String[] formats)
System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime (System.String value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode mode)
WinSCP.TouchEventArgs.Read (WinSCP.CustomLogReader areader)
WinSCP.Session.PutFiles (System.String localPath, System.String remotePath, Boolean remove, WinSCP.TransferOptions options)
MovesBoard_Controller.controller () (at Assets/MovesBoard_Controller.cs:193)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:153)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:634)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:769)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:53)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:35)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:44)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:52)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction1 functor) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:269)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()`

I don't think it's relevant, but I'm running this out of unity, it's to be triggered on a button press.

Taking any suggestions, cheers!

Comment: By the way, in your last catch block, you're concatenating the exception into the string instead of passing it as an argument to the Log method.

Comment: Yeah, that's just because Debug.Log doesn't support composite format strings and Console.WriteLine doesn't output to the unity console for me, but I forgot to get rid of the {0} when switching to concatenating, will edit.

Comment: What is the message of the exception? If you comment out the try blocks, which line does the exception occurr on?

Comment: Edited question to add the full message of the exception. The error occurs on the `transferResult = session.PutFiles(@"H:\toupload\*", "/home/opie/test.txt", false, transferOptions);` line if the try/catch is commented out.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the issue is with WinSCP's library. If you place a breakpoint on the line, then "Step in" and "Step over" until you're in `PutFiles` -> `TouchEventArgs.Read` -> `if(reader.GetEmptyElementValue("modification", out value))` block, what does the `value` argument look like?

Comment: What is default culture of your application?

Comment: Ugh, Unity is giving me grief with referencing a .dbg file so that I can step into the .dll's code. I've figured out a workaround, and don't have the time at work to spend on this bug. 

Should I delete the thread or leave it here in case anyone finds a quick fix? 

Thanks for trying guys <3

Comment: Set `Session.DebugLogPath` and show us the log.